# JFreeChart 's DateAxis Particular TickUnit

Tags: java, jfreechart

I create TimeSeriesChart using TimeSeriesCollection dataset. I use DateAxis for my x-axis and ValueAxis for y-axis.The problem is **DateAxis**.Check image

[image]

According to this image, the x-axis has so many values.I want x-axis DateTickUnit with particular value.Now my chart has 8 values. I only want that 8 values' dates. No need all dates points to display.Any suggestion for this?

Note: I don't want to switch from a Bar Rendered to a LineAndShapeRenderer  looks like an XYChart.Don't want this way [In jfreechart TimeSeriesCollection how to show dates which has only values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297851/in-jfreechart-timeseriescollection-how-to-show-dates-which-has-only-values)

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: @trashgod Please check my edited post.

Comment: In constructing your [mcve], see also [*Where is DateTickUnit documentation?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6348122/230513). Also consider supressing the unit display and using labels or tooltips.